# Problems understanding some basic concepts in power and effect size

Tags: effect-size, statistical-power

All of my confusion began when I tried to graphically demonstrate the effect of SD and mean difference to power when comparing to independent groups.

I drew a graph like this to demonstrate a Cohen´s d of 0.2 (from rpsychologist.com)

[image]

Then I tried to highlight the α, ie. the tails of the treatment population, to show the meaning of β and power. It is not clearly possible in a way the α is usually graphically depicted as in this screenshot from G*Power:
[image]

I understand that the X-axis in the G*Power indicates Z-score, ie. in this case 2.5% tail area matches to critical value of 1.96 times the population SD. How about the first graph? What am I missing here?

**Edit** If I mark the critical value for right 2.5% tail area in the treatment group to 1.96*SD, the area β in the treatment group is almost 90%. I reframe my question: In the G*power graph SD is 1 and the mean difference is ~2.8. How does this correspond to Cohen´s d of 0.2?

**Edit 2** I think the answer by whuber nails it. I had problems understanding that the first graph shows the population distribution whereas the G*Power graph shows the sampling distribution of means from the populations which are totally diffecent concepts.

In the G*Power graph, is the expected mean value (*true population value*) from population 1 (red) 0 and the respective value in the other population (blue) ~2.8? And just to make sure, effect size is always sample dependent and no graphical depiction of effect size is feasible when drawing sampling distribution?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "not clearly possible"?  Your picture is just like that in G*Power and works in the same way:  the dimensions are a little different, that's all.

Comment: Re the edit: where in your plot do you account for having two samples of size 394 each?  That's what G\*Power is using.  What exactly do your plots represent?  (The G\*Power answer is, *the sampling distributions of the means*; it should not be the distributions of the populations, which I suspect might be what you have drawn.)

Comment: @whuber: That was the point I was asking. I added a follow-up question.